# "Cannot add the item to shopping cart." For no apparent reason

Tags: cart, error

I have a slightly strange problem that I need your help with.

I have three independent Magento installations on my server. Two of which under an SSL certificate as such: https ://apps.domain.com/store1 & https ://apps.domain.com/store2. Both of these stores how custom themes. The third installation is a fresh install on the root of the domain without an SSL certificate as such: http:// www.domain.com/store3

What happens is that, all of a sudden, all three stores stop being able to add items to cart and give me this error "Cannot add the item to shopping cart.". And then an hour or a couple of hours later or so, the add to cart buttons start working again. The weird thing is that I don't change anything to make it work or stop working, and they all work or stop working simultaneously.

I'm using magento 1.8.

Please advise!

**Update**:

Actually I found this in my exception log:

```
2014-07-27T21:09:35+00:00 DEBUG (7): Exception message: Notice: Undefined offset: 2  in /home/---/store2/lib/Zend/Locale/Format.php on line 577
Trace: #0 /home/---/store2/lib/Zend/Locale/Format.php(577): mageCoreErrorHandler(8, 'Undefined offse...', '/home/vmegypt/p...', 577, Array)
1 /home/---/store2/lib/Zend/Locale/Format.php(513): Zend_Locale_Format::_getRegexForType('decimalnumber', Array)
2 /home/---/store2/lib/Zend/Filter/LocalizedToNormalized.php(100): Zend_Locale_Format::isNumber('3', Array)
3 /home/---/store2/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php(187): Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized->filter('3')
4 /home/---/store2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Checkout_CartController->addAction()
5 /home/---/store2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('add')
6 /home/---/store2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
7 /home/---/store2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
8 /home/---/store2/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
9 /home/---/store2/index.php(117): Mage::run('', 'store')
10 {main}
2014-07-27T21:09:35+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Exception' with message 'Notice: Undefined offset: 2  in /home/---/store2/lib/Zend/Locale/Format.php on line 577' in /home/---/store2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php:245
Stack trace:
0 /home/---/store2/lib/Zend/Locale/Format.php(577): mageCoreErrorHandler(8, 'Undefined offse...', '/home/vmegypt/p...', 577, Array)
1 /home/---/store2/lib/Zend/Locale/Format.php(513): Zend_Locale_Format::_getRegexForType('decimalnumber', Array)
2 /home/---/store2/lib/Zend/Filter/LocalizedToNormalized.php(100): Zend_Locale_Format::isNumber('3', Array)
3 /home/---/store2/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php(187): Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized->filter('3')
4 /home/---/store2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Checkout_CartController->addAction()
5 /home/---/store2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('add')
6 /home/---/store2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
7 /home/---/store2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
8 /home/---/store2/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
9 /home/---/store2/index.php(117): Mage::run('', 'store')
10 {main}
```

Comment: check var/log for error messages.

Comment: It sounds like a session issue, where are you storing your sessions?

Comment: Try to clear your cookies and try again. Does it work in the first store? And then not in the second?

Comment: @Marius: I checked the system and exception logs. No errors that are relevant there. No errors are triggered by the add to cart action.

Comment: @brentwpeterson I'm storing my sessions on file system.

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt I still have the same issue even when I use the store in a Chrome Incognito window. It appears that as soon as it breaks in one store it breaks in the others as well. Then later they all start working again together for a few minutes until they all break again.

Is there such a thing as the sessions conflicting with each other? Or perhaps a timezones and server time issue?

Comment: I've posted an update

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22630194/3881568

This fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the session files are being written? (i.e. look when you are not able to add to cart and see if there are sessions files being written)

Comment: Can you provide info regarding the involved locales? Do you have any further updates?

Answer (score 1):

OP noted that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22578195/magento-cart-not-updating-quantity-in-arabic-store-view/22630194#22630194) to "Magento cart not updating quantity in arabic store view" solved his issue.

This is a tenuous fix though. It's not apparent how this could be an *intermittent* issue given the Zend component referenced in the fix.

Comment: I have same issue on magento 1.9.2.4 (arabic process worked)whats we do ? can we follow this process and this right?